# Clarity lazy loaded clr-tree clrSelected failure

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I'm trying to implement a Clarity lazy-loaded `clr-tree`. My data model of nodes contains a "selected" field. When I set this as indicated in the docs on `clr-tree-node`, the initial load of the tree is null, and the `clrSelected` attributes errors out the entire view.

Here's my Angular template code for the tree:

```html
<clr-tree [clrLazy]="true" *ngIf="initialized">
    <clr-tree-node *clrRecursiveFor="let setnode of root$ | async; getChildren: getChildren"
        [clrExpandable]="setnode?.nodeType == 'S'" [(clrSelected)]="setnode.selected">
        <cds-icon [attr.shape]="setnode?.nodeType == 'S' ? 'factory' : 'flask'"></cds-icon>
        {{setnode?.labelText}}
    </clr-tree-node>
</clr-tree>
```

The `$root` is set in the component as an `Observable<SetNode>` that is a result of my HTTP client call. The `getChildren` call returns the same Observable.

Here is the error I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null

This appears to be coming from the `[(clrSelected)]="setnode.selected"` section of the `clr-tree-node` element. I know this has to do with the template rendering before the Observable finishes, I'm just not sure how to tell the `clrSelected` to ignore it until it finishes, as otherwise `setnode` is null.

Alternatively, is there another way to get the `clr-tree` out of read-only mode?  Without the `clrSelected`, the `clr-tree` does not allow for selection (highlighting) of nodes.

Comment: This question post was based on my misunderstanding of Clarity treeview terms highlight vs. select (which uses checkboxes for node selection).  I was looking for highlighting.  Closing question.

Answer (score 0):

The failure is at the Angular level, where it cannot resolve the binding in the template. You already have the solution in a few places, use the `?.` operator to address this issue.

```
[(clrSelected)]="setnode?.selected"
```

Comment: Tried setnode?.selected.  This doesn't appear to be allowed when using 2-way binding.